# Unexpected behavior of Meta-RET in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

when using lists in org-mode, the `Meta-RET` binding does not behave as expected. What I expect is that the binding will create a new item at the same level as the previous item. What I get is a new line indented to the level of the last item.

When I check the binding with `C-h k [M-RET]`, it tells me that it is an alias for:

```
comment-indent-new-line
```

whereas I expect something like `org-meta-return`. Why is it so?

How can I change the behavior of `M-RET` so it behaves as I except with org-mode?

I am using Emacs 23.1.1 and org-mode 6.21b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was trying to better ask my question, I found how to change the binding effectively.

### Interactively

```
M-x global-key [RET] [M-RET] [RET] org-mode-return
```

Which actually helped me to redefine it at init, since it returns the actual binding Emacs is using (`C-M-j`).

### At init

I added to my `.emacs` file the following:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-j") 'org-meta-return)
```

Which does exactly what I wanted.

While I still don't understand why I got the behavior I mentioned, at least now I get the one I expect.

Comment: It could be the org version is very out of date and not like the current documentation. The current major version of org is 9.0, and it probably requires a newer emacs version.

Comment: Thanks for the possible explanation. I would have upgrade the version if possible, but it happened on a machine on which I have no administrative rights.